# Insert a large dataframe into Hadoop table using Python

Tags: python, sql, pandas, hadoop, hive

I have a big data frame **df** for which I have attached below sample image. It contains of 47000 rows which I want to insert into a Hadoop table. The table where I want to insert this data has all the **string** columns.. All the columns in the pandas dataframe have **object** datatype.

```
keyword,category_l1,category_l2,brand,ordercode,sku,snp_subclass,date
```

[image: Df]

I have tried using the below cursor solution for which i am getting an error.
Also I am looking for a faster approach than using cursor.
I have tried the below solution

```
with pyodbc.connect("DSN=hadoop",autocommit=True) as conx:
    cursor = conx.cursor()
    cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO ast_labs_t.dcs_search_keywords_nlp_results_test (keyword,category_l1,category_l2,brand,ordercode,sku,snp_subclass) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", df)
```

I am getting the below error:

```
The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 7 parameters were supplied', 'HY000')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider using spark.

```
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

#create spark dataframe from pandas dataframe
spark_df = hive_context.createDataFrame(df)

#Register temp view from spark df
spark_df.createOrReplaceTempView('MyTempTable')

#Now use hive query to insert from temp view

hive_context.sql("INSERT INTO ast_labs_t.dcs_search_keywords_nlp_results_test select keyword,category_l1,category_l2,brand,ordercode,sku,snp_subclass from MyTempTable")
```

Comment: .AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'keyword' given input columns: [mytemptable._1, mytemptable._2, mytemptable._3, mytemptable._4, mytemptable._5, mytemptable._6, mytemptable._7]; line 1 pos 56;
'InsertIntoStatement 'UnresolvedRelation [dcs_search_keywords_nlp_results_test], [], false, false, false
+- 'Project ['keyword, 'category_l1, 'category_l2, 'brand, 'ordercode, 'sku, 'snp_subclass]
   +- SubqueryAlias mytemptable
      +- View (`MyTempTable`, [_1#76,_2#77,_3#78,_4#79,_5#80,_6#81,_7#82])
         +- LogicalRDD [_1#76, _2#77, _3#78, _4#79, _5#80, _6#81, _7#82], false

Comment: This is the error i am getting after running the code

Comment: @Developer df1 dataframe contains no column names.  Add them using columns attribute

Comment: I am trying to use the below dataframe

Comment: I have updated the dataframe picture in my question,. Now i am getting the following typecasting error. TypeError: field dcs_search_keywords_nlp.keyword: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>

Comment: @Please add the dataframe content to the question, not the answer. And also please add table definition

Comment: I am getting the below error now.  AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'category_l1' given input columns: [mytemptable.Brand, mytemptable.Order Code, mytemptable.Predicted Label, mytemptable.SKU, mytemptable.SnP Subclass, mytemptable.Subcategory, mytemptable.keyword]; line 1 pos 75;
'InsertIntoStatement 'UnresolvedRelation [ast_labs_t, dcs_search_keywords_nlp_results_test], [], false, false, false
+- 'Project [keyword#28, 'category_l1, 'category_l2, brand#31, 'ordercode, sku#33, 'snp_subclass]
   +- SubqueryAlias mytemptable
      +- View (`MyTempTable`, [keyword#28,Predicted

Comment: I have edited the question to include the dataframe. My table where I want to insert has all string columns. I have typecasted the pandas dataframe to str datatype as I was facing type casting error. I have removed dots in the df column names to resolve some error. Still Im getting the error I mentioned in the comment above. My table has keyword,category_l1,category_l2,brand,ordercode,sku,snp_subclass these columns all of string data type